# LibGdx label background with 9patch

Tags: java, android, libgdx, label, nine-patch

So i've come across this problem that i simply can't manage to sort out.
I'm making a game with the help of LibGdx and am trying to create a chat bubble functionality. The problem is, when i try to change the background of the label style to a 9patch drawable, it doesn't scale it well, or at all?

```
public class ChatBubble
{
    private Label textLabel;
    private BitmapFont font;
    private Label.LabelStyle lStyle;
    private int scaledWidth = 0;
    private int scaledHeight = 0;
    private Timer.Task currentTask;
    private Texture bkg;

    public ChatBubble()
    {
        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        bkg = new Texture("data/ui/chatb.9.png");

        NinePatch np = new NinePatch(bkg,11,11,9,10);
        NinePatchDrawable npd = new NinePatchDrawable(np);
        lStyle = new Label.LabelStyle(font,font.getColor());
        lStyle.background = npd;

        textLabel = new Label("",lStyle);
        textLabel.setVisible(false);
        textLabel.setAlignment(Align.center);
        currentTask = new Timer.Task() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textLabel.setVisible(false);
            }};
    }

    public void show(String text, float duration)
    {
        if(currentTask.isScheduled())currentTask.cancel();
        textLabel.setText(text);
        textLabel.setVisible(true);
        scaledHeight = (int)textLabel.getPrefHeight();
        scaledWidth = (int)textLabel.getWidth()/2;
        Timer.schedule(currentTask,duration);
    }

    public void show(String text)
    {
        if(currentTask.isScheduled())currentTask.cancel();
        textLabel.setText(text);
        textLabel.setVisible(true);
        scaledHeight = (int)textLabel.getPrefHeight();
        scaledWidth = (int)textLabel.getWidth()/2;
        Timer.schedule(currentTask,(float)(text.length()*0.1));
    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float x, float y)
    {
        if(!textLabel.isVisible())return;
        textLabel.setPosition(x - scaledWidth, y + scaledHeight);
        batch.begin();
        textLabel.draw(batch, 1);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

How it looks ingame:
[image: How it looks ingame]

How the 9batch looks:
[image: 9patch]

Any help would be appreciated!

Update:
I've found out that my 9patch scales ok, the problem being in label not updating it's size when setText() is called, thus having it width and height 0 since constructor was "".. calling layout() on label doesn't solve this either.

Answer (score 0):

Call `.pack()` on the label after `.setText()` to tell it to size itself to its text (plus whatever padding there is in the background drawable). You don't need to call `layout()` since that's handled automatically.

I'm not sure the exact reason you have to manually call `pack()`, but this is generally the case with Widgets that you are not children of a WidgetGroup subclass (i.e. Table, VerticalGroup, etc.).

Comment: i have tried it before, doesn't change anything unfortunately. 
The way i solved this for now is label = new label("",stylewithbkg);
every time i show a new chat bubble.. this is not very smart memory wise tho :(